# After svn update, code is updated but changes are not showing on was server

Tags: spring, svn, websphere, ibm-rad

One of my team member has committed some changes to the Spring project that we are working on. Now I have taken SVN update in RAD (Rational Application Developer). All of my code is updated. But when I am running the WAS (webSphere application server) server, no changes are visible on localhost.